# O que significa «anto»?

Tags: significado

Numa música de A Naifa, falando-se de coisas de que se gosta, aparece a palavra *anto*.

> Gosto da cidade e da publicidade
>   Gosto do campo **e do anto**
>   Gosto do mar e do lar
>   Gosto do ar e do radar
>   Gosto do céu e do chapéu
>   Gosto da praia e da saia
>   Gosto de ti e de ti

Mas o que é *anto*?

Não consigo perceber, e nenhum dicionário me conseguiu ajudar:

- O [Priberam](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/anto) não tem entrada;
- O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/anto) não tem nada relacionado;
- O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=anto) também não.

Comment: Achei isso, algo relacionado a um prefixo de flor. https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/anto

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade é *Anto*, com letra grande, como se pode ver na [página de Facebook da banda](https://www.facebook.com/notes/a-naifa/os-poemas/10150345177583414/). A letra da canção combina os poemas “Gosto da cidade” e “Marianna e Chamily” de [Adília Lopes (Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad%C3%ADlia_Lopes) e [Facebook)](https://www.facebook.com/Ad%C3%ADlia-Lopes-233858583360494/). *Anto* é o único substantivo com inicial maiúscula no poema:

> Gosto da cidade
>   E da publicidade
>
> Gosto do campo
>   E do Anto
>   […]

Este *Anto* refere-se provavelmente ao  poeta português [António Nobre (1867 – 1900, Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B3nio_Pereira_Nobre). Ele foi ainda em adolescente alcunhado de *Anto*, redução de *António*, por uma preceptora inglesa sua. Ele assumiu a alcunha, e o seu mais famoso livro, *Só* (1892), fecha com o poema [“Males de Anto”](http://www.citador.pt/poemas/males-de-anto-antonio-nobre). O poema tem como subtítulo “A ares numa aldeia” e está cheio de imagens campestres, daí talvez a ligação ao “campo” nos versos da canção, “Gosto do campo / E do Anto”. Que o *Anto* nos “Males de Anto” é o próprio autor não há duvida: no poema ele refere-se a si mesmo uma vez por António, outra por Anto. E já quanto tuberculoso, ele escreveu:

> Deus castigou-me. Quando era feliz e apenas tinha arranhaduras dos 19 anos, escrevia os Males de Anto, exagerando tudo. Agora é que eu os sinto, depois de os ter expresso em literatura.

Mais tarde, [Mário de Sá-Carneiro (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1rio_de_S%C3%A1-Carneiro) escreveu [“Anto” (1915)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Ltp7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&dq=%22caprichos%20de%20lil%C3%A1s%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiomMm_2tTUAhXBWxQKHThgAWIQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22caprichos%20de%20lil%C3%A1s%22&f=false), um poema de homenagem a António Nobre. Tudo isto e mais em [“O Enigma de Anto”, jornal *Publico*, 18-03-2000](https://www.publico.pt/noticias/jornal/o-enigma-de-anto-141437). Existe também em Coimbra a [Torre de Anto (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torre_de_Anto). A torre já vem da muralha medieval, mas passou a chamar-se assim depois e por causa de o poeta lá morar nos seus tempos de estudante.

---

Nos dicionários aparecem apenas os elementos compositivos *ant(o)-* (antepositivo), *-ant(o)-* (interpositivo) e *-anto* (pospositivo), já que o outro *Anto* é nome próprio.  Explica o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) que *ant(o)* vem do grego *ánthos,eos-ous*, significando ‘rebento, broto, flor’ e por isso também ‘erupção’. Não é uma palavra em sim mesma, mas entra na composição de palavras, como [*antologia*](http://www.aulete.com.br/antologia), [antúrio](http://www.aulete.com.br/ant%C3%BArio), [aperiantáceo](http://www.aulete.com.br/aperiant%C3%A1ceo) ou [*agapanto*.](http://www.aulete.com.br/agapanto)

Comment: E por qual motivo esse Anto está em letra minúscula? Já que é um apelido, deveria estar em letra maiscula?

Comment: @Peixoto, imagino que quem escreveu com minúscula não saiba que é *Anto*. Não creio que os sites que apresentam as letras das canções se preocupem muito em pesquisar as palavras que não conhecem. Na página de facebook da banda está *Anto*, com maiúscula.