# É o quê, isso de suíta?

Tags: significado, letras-de-músicas

Estava ouvindo aquele hino de Caetano e Buarque, e me deparei com uma palavra desconhecida.

> Eu me sento, eu fumo, eu como, eu não aguento
>   Você está tão curtida
>   Eu quero tocar fogo neste apartamento
>   Você não acredita
>   Traz meu café com **Suita** eu tomo
>   Bota a sobremesa eu como, eu como

É o quê, "*suíta*"?

Comment: Suita está escrito com letra maiúscula e isso já é uma pista.

Comment: Em alguns sítios, sim, @Centaurus, mas noutros não. Nos primeiros que vi encontrei «suíta», em minúsculas e com acento. :) Mas sim, a letra maiúscula alertou-me logo... aprendi [da primeira vez](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4555/o-que-significa-anto) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Suita" é um adoçante, um dos primeiros surgidos no Brasil.

O nome é assim meio derivado do inglês...

Meus obrigados a Aloe (Twitter [@vera](https://twitter.com/vera)), que [clarificou](https://twitter.com/vera/status/880428739112443905):

[image: uma embalagem de adoçante suita]

Comment: Puxa vida, cara, é mesmo! Brigado, viu? <3